# Executing command with multiple strings in pipe

Tags: c, pipe, dup2

I proceeded to create a child process with fork() so that the parent would send to the child, x consecutive strings in the form of "Line i" (1 <= i <= x) with the write command. The child should then proceed to execute the "more" command on every line. However the child when executing shows only the first line ("Line 1"). Is it necessary for me to send the whole string in one go with "write"?

```
int main(){

    pid_t pid;
    char buf[30];
    int fd[2],i,max;

    scanf("%d",&max);

    if(pipe(fd)<0) printf("Error creating pipe\n");

    if((pid=fork())<0) printf("Error forking\n");
    else if(pid==0){
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        if(execlp("more","more",NULL)<0) printf("Error executing.\n");
    }
    else{
        close(fd[0]);
        for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
            sprintf(buf, "Line %d\n", i);
            write(fd[1],buf,30);
        }
        close(fd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're writing uninitialized garbage to your pipe. Why do you use a buffer in the first place? A direct `fprintf()` to the pipe (`fdopen()` it first) would be simpler and avoid this error.

Comment: I guess that was really the case. Added a fflush() to the mix and now it's working 100%. Wasn't familiar with the fdopen() command so thanks for the assistance.